# descomponer una variable como si fuera un array

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, vb.net, .net

Tengo un pequeño problema.
 estoy diseñando un sitio web en aspx.net 
realizo una consulta a mi base de datos que me devuelve un un valor que asigno a una variable de la siguiente forma

Dim permisos As String
                permisos = objUsuario.rol_permisos

esta variable contiene una cadena de la siguiente forma "010101"

mi pregunta es, existe alguna forma de descomponer esta cadena como si fuera un array?

saludos y gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 2):

Estimado, el siguiente código te puede servir.

```
/* Tengo una variable permisos que es un string */
Dim permisos As String = "010203"

/* Creo el array "claveValor" de tipo String */
Dim claveValor() As String = {permisos.Substring(0, 2),
                              permisos.Substring(2, 2),
                              permisos.Substring(4, 2)}

/* Lo cargo en alguna parte, por ejemplo en un comboBox */
cbPermiso.MaxDropDownItems = claveValor.Length
For Each item As String In claveValor
    cbPermiso.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Como en varios lenguajes similares, un string es ya un array de caracteres

entonces tu puedes acceder ya a esos elementos como un array sin necesidad de hacer nada, más que colocar el indice que necesitas.

```
Console.WriteLine (permisos(0)) // Imprime 0
Console.WriteLine (permisos(1)) // Imprime 1 
Console.WriteLine (permisos(2)) // Imprime 0
Console.WriteLine (permisos(3)) // Imprime 1
Console.WriteLine (permisos(4)) // Imprime 0
Console.WriteLine (permisos(5)) // Imprime 1
```